# Hide Spanned Rows

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Here...The code i have added to filter the anchor link is not working.. And i want to know how to hide the spanned rows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Add click event for Hide anchor
            //This code not working.... why?.. 
           $("table tr td a").filter(function () { return $(this).text() == "Hide"; }).click(function (e) { RowHide(this); return false; })

            //working..but want to have filter.. $("table tr td a").click(function (e) { RowHide(this); return false; })

        });
        function RowHide(obj) {
            var index = $(obj).closest("tr").index();
            //How to hide the spanned row..i.e on clicking R4R5R6C1 Hide link...should hide R4,R5 & R6
          $("table").find("tr:eq(" + index + ") td").each(function () { $(this).hide() });
        }   


    </script>
```

In this table..Hide is working for all the rows..except spanned row..it's hiding only one row..

```
<table style="width:20%;border:1;border-style:solid">
        <tr>
            <td>
             Header 1
            <td> Header 2</td>
            <td>
               Header 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                R1C1</td>
            <td>
                R1C2</td> 
            <td>
                R1C3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                R2C1<br />
                <a href="#"> Hide </a>
                </td>
            <td>
                R2C2</td>
            <td>
                R2C3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                R3C1
                <br />
                <a href="#"> Hide </a>
                </td>
            <td>
                R3C2</td>
            <td>
                R3C3</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">
                R4R5R6C1
                <br />
                <a href="#"> Hide </a>
                </td>
            <td>
                R4C2</td> 
            <td>
                R4C3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <td>
                R5C2</td>
            <td>
                R5C3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>
                R6C2</td> 
            <td>
                R6C3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit] I had misunderstood the problem initially.

Try this now, I think it's what you were after [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smendola/8yvdT/)